# Silverlight search validation

Tags: silverlight

what is a clean way to validate this scenario, I have 3 textboxes for search..FirstName, LastName, and Age and my requirement is to atleast enter one of the 3 search items. So not all of them are required, but the user has to atleast enter one of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pressing search button (or invoking search command) check:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) || (Age != null))
```

if not - raise `ValidationException` with description of problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I was hoping there is a way to do this using data annotations.